# How to make a computed property that depends on a global class attribute?

Tags: ember.js

I wanna create a property that depends on a global attribute:

```
App.Test= Em.Object.extend();
App.Test.reopenClass({ all: Em.A() });

App.Other = Em.object.extend({
  stuff: function() {
    return "calculated stuff from this.get('foo') and App.Test.all";
  }.property('foo', 'App.Test.all.@each.bar')
});
```

As a workarround I could create a observer and always set a dummy property with a new random value to trigger the property change, but is there a better way to do this?

I need this for some caching. I've a really crazy, and single threaded backend. So I write my own Model classes. So I try to reimplement a bit of the logic in the client for a better caching.

Ive an Item class (App.Item) and another class where each instance has a calculated reduced list of Items.

```
App.Model = Em.Object.extend({
});
App.Model.reopenClass({
  all: Em.A(),
  load: function(hash) {
    return this.get('all').pushObject(this.create(hash));
  }
});

App.Item = App.Model.extend({

});

App.List = App.Model.extend({
  loadedInitItems: false,
  items: function() {
    if(!this.get('loadedInitItems')) { this.set('loadedInitItems', true); Backend.call('thelist', function(item) { App.Item.load(this); }); }
    return App.Item.all.filter(function(item) {
      // heavy filter stuff, depends on a lot of propertys on the current list instance
    });
  }.property('someprops', 'App.Item.all.@each.foo')
});
```

Backend.call represents some AJAX stuff

the point is, that now any item could change so that the filter will return something diffrent. And there are other places om the application, where the user can add Items. I dont want to call the backend again, because its very slow! And I know that the backend will not modify the list! So I wanna cache it.

This is just a reduced example of my use case, but I think've described the point. In reallity I have this dozend of times, with over 25000 objects.

Comment: could you explain more in detail what your use case is, it looks like you are fighting the framework...

Comment: @intuitivepixel
I've tried to explain it a bit. All about caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the double uppercase letter. So `App.test` ist working, but not `App.Foo.test`.

But I was able to find a Solution with the ArrayProxy.

Its about this:

```
App.Model = Em.Object.extend({
});
App.Model.reopenClass({
    all: Em.A(),
    load: function(hash) {
        return this.get('all').pushObject(this.create(hash));
    }
});

App.Item = App.Model.extend({

});

App.List = App.Model.extend({
    loadedInitItems: false,
    items: function() {
        var self = this;
        if(!this.get('loadedInitItems')) { 
            this.set('loadedInitItems', true);
            Backend.call('thelist', function(item) {
                App.Item.load(this);
            }); 
        }

        return Em.ArrayProxy.extend({
            content: App.Item.all,
            arrangedContent: function() {
                return this.get('content').filter(function(item) {
                    // heavy filter stuff, depends on a lot of propertys on the current list instance
                    // use self.get('someprops')
                })
            }.property('content.@each.foo')
        });
    }.property('someprops')

    items: function() {
        if(!this.get('loadedInitItems')) { this.set('loadedInitItems', true); Backend.call('thelist', function(item) { App.Item.load(this); }); }
        return App.Item.all.filter(function(item) {
// heavy filter stuff, depends on a lot of propertys on the current list instance
});
    }.property('someprops', 'App.Item.all.@each.foo')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried adding 'Binding' to your property and then the value you want to bind to ?, something like this:

```
App.PostsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  nameOfYourVariableBinding: "App.SomeObject.propertyYouWantToBindTo"
})
```